# React access setState in array map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to update a state inside a array map, but it gives me an error that `setState` is not a function on `this`. How can I acheive this? My code snippet is given below

```
this.setState({
  isLoading: true
});

this.state.questions.map(function(key, value) {
  if (key.id === undefined) {
    axios
      .post("/api/questions/create", key)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: true
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {});
  } else {
    axios
      .post("/api/questions/update/" + key.id, key)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: true
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {});
  }
});
```

Comment: Put `this` in a variable.

Comment: this.state.questions.map(function(key, value) { }) will not bind your `this` values but in ES6 arrow functions bind(this) keyword

Comment: you can also try this `this.state.questions.map(function(key, value) { ...//stuff }).bind(this)`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a fat arrow syntax in your `map` instead.

Change this: `this.state.questions.map(function(key, value) {`

To this: `this.state.questions.map((key, value) => {`

---

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords.

Read more about arrow functions, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 1):

Look into [**THIS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)  for detailed working nature of `this` keyword and [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for detailed info about `=>` functions. Hope the docs helps in better understanding.

```
this.setState({
        isLoading: true,
    });

    this.state.questions.map((key, value) => {

      let that = this; // assigning this to a variable

        if ( key.id === undefined ) {

            axios.post('/api/questions/create', key)
                .then((response) => {

                   that.setState({ 
                        isLoading: true,
                    });

                })
                .catch((error) => {  

                });

        } else {

            axios.post('/api/questions/update/' + key.id, key)
                .then((response) => {

                    that.setState({
                        isLoading: true,
                    });

                })
                .catch((error) =>{

                });

        }
    });
```